# Browser Add-ons for blocking facebook.com outside facebook.com domain

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, facebook

Are there any Add-ons for Firefox OR Google Chrome that prevents links loading when not on facebook.com?

Why?
 - tracking
 - security

So if someone clicks on a link that points to facebook.com then it shouldnt load, only the "someone" was on facebook.com.
I can't find an add-on that does this, or even one with ~~similar functions.

Comment: do you mean "don't follow a clicked link if it points to facebook" or "don't load or display scripts and images from facebook"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more targeted addon for Firefox you might find useful: [FacebookBlocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facebookblocker/)

That should go a fair way in blocking Facebook stuff on sites on than Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox Noscript extension (http://noscript.net/) does this nicely.  This extension, however, affects many other things and you won't like it unless you are willing to spend some time enabling sites you want to function fully.